# Send packets to Source Dedicated Server

Tags: node.js, sockets, dart, packet, steam

I'm trying to write an RCON Client in dart, but I'm getting stuck at this point:

The server recives the packet but seems like it cannot read it properly as reply I'm getting:

> Rcon auth failed from rcon whitelist address 2.xxx.xxx.169:52672

Even tough the password is right:

> "rcon_password" = "foo" ( def. "" ) - remote console password.

I've provided links to the [valve's wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol) within the code comments.

This is my code at the moment:

```
Socket socket;
int _id = 1;

const int SERVERDATA_AUTH = 3;
const int SERVERDATA_AUTH_RESPONSE = 2;
const int SERVERDATA_EXECCOMMAND = 2;
const int SERVERDATA_RESPONSE_VALUE = 0;

void main() async {
    socket = await Socket.connect('hexah.net', 27015);
    await socket.listen(onSocketData, onError: onError, onDone: onDone);
    await _write(SERVERDATA_AUTH, 'foo');
}


void _write(int type, String body) async {

    var bodyASCII = ascii.encode(body); //Get ASCII string with Null terminator

    // Should I use this or the other way? ??
    var size = bodyASCII.length + 14;
    var buffer = new Int8List(size).buffer;
    var bdata = new ByteData.view(buffer);

    bdata.setInt32(0, size - 4, Endian.little); //Byte requests length (32bit le signed int).
    bdata.setInt32(4, _id, Endian.little); //Any integer (32bit le signed int).
    bdata.setInt32(8, type, Endian.little); //Valid values: SERVERDATA_* (32bit le signed int).
    int writepos = 12;
    await bodyASCII.forEach((element) {
        bdata.setInt8(writepos, element);
        writepos +=1;
    });
    bdata.setInt16(size-2, 0, Endian.little); //Write the null terminators
    await socket.write(bdata);
    _id++;
}

void onSocketData(var data){
    print(data);
}

void onError(var data, StackTrace stack){
    print(stack);
}

void onDone(){
    print('Connection terminated');
}
```

Here is also a small example with [nodejs](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol#Node.js):

```
var size   = Buffer.byteLength(body) + 14,
buffer = new Buffer(size);

buffer.writeInt32LE(size - 4, 0);
buffer.writeInt32LE(id,       4);
buffer.writeInt32LE(type,     8);
buffer.write(body, 12, size - 2, "ascii");
buffer.writeInt16LE(0, size - 2);
```

Do you have any ideas?
especially about getting properly the lengths.

This is how the [packet payload](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_RCON_Protocol#Basic_Packet_Structure) should be
 [image: Packet payload]

Using a `RawSocket` I get this as reply:

> RawSocketEvent.write
>
> RawSocketEvent.readClosed

EDIT:

I'm seeing that the same packet sent from nodejs resulted in a successful authentication but Dart failes, any ideas why this is happening? (converting the packets from nodejs & dart to an array they resulted the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The issue was that I had to use a RawSocket and write something like this:

```
var packet = bdata.buffer.asInt8List();
await socket.write(packet, 0, packet.length);
```